# Why fetch isn't working second time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

This is a very very annoying thing, i'm trying to solve it for hours right now. Here's the code:

```js
//ExpressJS code
    
app.post('/newname', (req, res) => {
    const {name, type, id} = req.body;
    console.log(name, type, id)
    knex('fl').insert({
        name, type, id,
        ...type === 'category'? {timeValue: req.body.timeValue, timeType: req.body.timeType} : {}
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("bar"); 
        return knex('fl').select('*').where('status', 'available')})
    .then(data => res.json(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
    
    
    //React code
    
    possibleName = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            possibleName: event.target.value
        })
        console.log(this.state.possibleName)
    }
    
    complete = () => {
        if(Boolean(this.state.possibleName)){
            console.log(this.state.possibleName)
            fetch('http://localhost:3001/newname', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    name: this.state.possibleName,
                    type: this.state.type,
                    id: this.props.id,
                    ...this.state.type === 'category'? {timeValue: this.props.timeValue, timeType: this.props.timeType}:{}
                })
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log("foo");
                this.props.dispatch(getAction(data));
                this.setState({
                    create: 'none',
                    zindex: 0,
                    possibleName: ''
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }
    }
    
    //...
    //...
    <input type='text' value={this.state.possibleName} onChange={this.possibleName}/>
    <div onClick={this.complete}></div>
```

So... The first time the div is clicked, everything works fine. All the logs are in the console. The second time, the `complete()`'s first log happens, but it seems like the fetch isn't happening. What's the reason? Something blocks the second fetch? If i try it with Postman, with the same format of `req.body`, everything works fine every time i try it. So i don't know what will be the problem.

Another thing that might the source of the problem i think, is that there's a dispatch. It's possible that redux don't let the fetch to finish? I mean the first fetch begins, but not completes, so if i fetch second time, it get into query, and starts when the fetch before finishes?

Comment: After the fetch finishes, you set `possibleName` to `''`. The fetch only runs when `possibleName` is truthy, so the second time it doesn't do anything. Try moving the first console.log outside of the `if` statement to get a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to show the another function in my code. There's an input field where `possibleName` updates every time of input. The first `console.log` executes every time i click on the button, but the fetch not.

Comment: So you know the `complete` function is running because that first `console.log`, but the fetch doesn't seem to do anything? Does the request actually happen? Check the devtool's network panel.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i got the problem. The problem was an another wrong coded function, wich repeadately called fetch, that's why the actual second fetch didn't finished.

Comment: You can give an answer, i'll upvote, and accept it, @Sidney. Thank you, again.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure I understand the problem, I wouldn't know what to put in an answer. But I'm glad you figured it out!